# Out of memory while writing a big file with MemoryDrawing images (PhpSpreasheet)

Tags: php, memory-management, phpspreadsheet

I'm currently trying to export a list of products (from an API, around 6000 products) to an .xlsx file where I list the product name and its thumbnail.

For text values everything is fine, but I'm trying to render the image directly in the spreadsheet, using `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\MemoryDrawing`.

My issue is after a certain amount of generated image, my process runs out of memory.

Here's my code:

```php
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet       = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

        $sheet->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);

        foreach ($products as $k => $product) {
            $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $k+1, $product['ref']);
            $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $k+1)->setDataType(DataType::TYPE_STRING);
            $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $k+1, $product['title']);

            if (empty($product['image'])) {
                continue;
            }

            $drawing = new MemoryDrawing();
            $sheet->getRowDimension($k+1)->setRowHeight(80);

            $gdImage = substr_count($imagePath, '.png') ? imagecreatefrompng($imagePath) : imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath);
            $drawing->setName('Thumbnail');
            $drawing->setDescription('Thumbnail');
            $drawing->setResizeProportional(true);
            $drawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
            $drawing->setRenderingFunction(substr_count($imagePath, '.png') ? MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_PNG : MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
            $drawing->setMimeType(MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
            $drawing->setHeight(80);
            $drawing->setOffsetX(0);
            $drawing->setOffsetY(0);
            $drawing->setCoordinates('C'.($k+1));
            $drawing->setWorksheet($sheet);

            unset($drawing);
        }

        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
        $writer->save($filePath);
```

I've also tried to write my file, unset the spreadsheet and reload it every 100 or 200 lines, but I'm losing all the memory images written before.

```php
        if ($k % 100 === 0) {
            $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
            $writer->save($filePath);
            $spreadsheet->disconnectWorksheets();
            $spreadsheet->garbageCollect();
            unset($spreadsheet);
            unset($sheet);

            $reader      = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
            $spreadsheet = $reader->load($filePath);
            $sheet       = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        }
```

Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

try this (persist result in the file system and not in memory)

```
$drawing->setWorksheet($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet());
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('my_file.xlsx');
```